# How to smoothing phaser/canvas line?

Tags: javascript, canvas, phaser-framework

I've tried `lineCap` but it doesn't help.

The same geometry in SVG looks much better.

How to draw it with smoothing like in SVG or any "painters" like photoshop?

[image]

```js
  var game=new Phaser.Game(800,600,Phaser.AUTO,'game',{preload:preload,create:create, update:update});

function preload() {
      game.time.advancedTiming = true;
    }
  function create(){
    var graphics=game.add.graphics(300,10);  
    
    // graphics.beginFill(0xC7CFBE);
    graphics.lineStyle(7,0xB8B8B8,1);
    graphics.moveTo(10,10);
    graphics.lineTo(66, 10);
    graphics.lineTo(66,1380);
    graphics.lineTo(10,1380);
    graphics.lineTo(10,10);
    //graphics.endFill();
    graphics.angle = -2.699999999990382;
    
    window.graphics=graphics;
  }

   function update() 
    {
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/phaser/2.4.6/phaser.min.js"></script>
<div id="game"></div>
```

Comment: Do you have a live sample online we can look at?

Comment: @klewis http://s2.micp.ru/XS3S6.png press this blue button :)